# Google Apps Script time-based hourly trigger being called multiple times an hour

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I have a very simple Apps Script function with exactly one trigger - a time based trigger that runs once an hour.

[image]

However, a couple times a day seemingly at random it executes multiple times, which is causing issues in the sheet it affects. In this screenshot, it is running 5 times between 12-1.

[image: Executes 5 times at 12]

Is there any known reason why this is happening? I have gone over my code execution repeatedly and there doesn't seem to be any reason it's running multiple times.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't run it manually? How often does this happen? Can you reliably reproduce this? Have you reproduced it in multiple scripts?

Answer (score 2):

I am seeing the same behavior. It occurred twice in the last 24 hours.

Google's "My Triggers" page shows only one entry with parameters "Time-driven", "Hour timer", "Every hour".

Sometimes the routine is executed 2 or 3 times. For instance, Google's "My executions" page this morning shows runs at 7:33:26 AM, 7:33:04 AM, 7:32:26 AM.

My routine records to Logger.log() the data object that is passed in as the first argument. Its properties were identical every time: {year=2020.0, authMode=FULL, week-of-year=30.0, day-of-week=1.0, timezone=UTC, triggerUid=4350572, minute=31.0, day-of-month=20.0, second=28.0, hour=11.0, month=7.0}.

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar issue. I have a script with a daily time trigger. It should only be running 1 time per day, but this afternoon, it ran 3 times within a minute of each other.

Oddly, I used this exact same trigger and script on a different google sheet and it worked fine.

Comment: Are you by any chance using Utilities.sleep() ?